# Express route controller works inline but not exported - PassportJS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm coding a login post route using passport JS. It works fine, but I'm having issues getting my exported version working.

Works

```
router.post('/users/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
});
```

Doesn't work - Returns Cannot POST /users/login

```
exports.loginAuth = passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
}
```

Comment: have you defined the passport LocalStrategy? once you define the strategy, you can use it in your 'post' http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKi, one thing. on yow `loginAuth` where are you telling the route ?
Well the problem is bcuz you of `passport.authenticate('local'),` that is a middleware

try this. let's say we have the `routes.js` and the `controller.js`

on the `rotes.js` as the name says we have them routes, so it looks like this

```js
import {Router} from "express";
//const {Router} = require("express");
import {theEndPoint} from "./controller";
 
export default function themRoutes () {
 const api = Router()

// also dont forget to add the require them thingies required by passport and stuff
api.post("/api/login", [passport.authenticate('local')],theEndPoint);


return api;
}
```

and on our `controller.js` file we have some like

```js
export function theEndPoint (req, res) {

....

res.sendStatus(202);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I had to leave passport.auth in the route and pass the middleware function after. Thanks!